# Replacing images in custom adapter - AsyncTask / multiple threads

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

What I have in place is an `AsyncTask` which loads a list of files and folders and places them in my custom Listview using my custom Adapter.

This custom Listview has an ImageView as well as a TextView.

When the list is initially loaded, I load a 'dummy' image for each file and folder (I just use a drawable).  I do this so the list loads quickly.

Once this first Async task has completed, I then want to replace any dummy drawable images with the REAL image thumbnail (this is coming from dropbox).

SO - to do this part I simply start another `AsyncTask` to do so.  It loads each thumbail one by one and replaces the default dummy image in the adapter with the real one.

I use onProgressUpdate to refresh the adapter so the ListView gets updated after each thumbnail is downloaded.  It seems to work ok, the images are downloaded, replaced and the user can still scroll as the images get updated.

**PROBLEM:**
Its quite slow.  Takes between 1-2 seconds to retrieve a single thumbnail and load it.

**QUESTION:**

1. Is there a way I can have multiple threads downloading the
   thumbnails so they load in batches of e.g. 10 at a time?  Without freezing the UI!
2. The problem I see is knowing where in the adapter to put the
   thumbnail once it has been downloaded (see my code for how I
   currently do this using an int counter).

Here is my AsyncTask for getting the real thumbnails and replacing the dummy images. It downloads the images from dropbox one at a time.  Be good if I could do this in several threads!

```
 private class loadActualThumbs extends AsyncTask<DbxFileSystem, Integer, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {

        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean  doInBackground(DbxFileSystem... params) {
            //Opens thumbnails for each image contained in the dropbox folder
            try {
                DbxFileSystem fileSystem = params[0];
                DbxFile file = null;
                int loopCount=0; //I use this to identify where in the adapter the real image should go

                for (DbxFileInfo fileInfo: fileSystem.listFolder(currentPath)) {

                    try{

                        if(fileInfo.thumbExists) // if it has a thumbnail then retrieve it
                        {
                            file = fileSystem.openThumbnail(fileInfo.path, ThumbSize.S, ThumbFormat.PNG);
                            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(file.getReadStream());
                            pix.set(loopCount,image); //replace the default image with the real one
                            loopCount++;
                            publishProgress(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // its a folder so no image needed
                            loopCount++;//still need to increment this though

                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.gc();
                }

                file.close(); //close the file outside of the loop

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } finally {

            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {

               //we want to load the image here to the adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        }
}
```

Comment: From further reading I may be able to call my AsyncTask like this, but I'm guessing even if it does work, the images could get loaded in the wrong place in the adapter: thumbs.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,dbxFs );

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It loads all your images in the background, caches them if you desire, and you can set how many will be downloaded at once (number of threads).

Comment: I have looked at this and it does not suit my purpose.  Mainly because you are required to use URLs to download the image.  If you have a quick look at my code, you will see I am using the dropbox SDK which does not provide you with URLs for the thumbnails.  The only way to get the thumbnail is to decodeStream into a Bitmap.

Comment: Ah my mistake. Didn't realize.